# Default React Favicon shows up on pdf view instead of customized one

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, favicon

I have the following file structure in my React App - public folder:

[image]

So my custom favicon that I added(*instead of the default React one that I deleted*) is working fine, it shows up. Now when the pdf opens in the browser it shows the React favicon.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951421/favicon-not-showing-up-when-displaying-a-pdf-how-to-make-it-show-up) that the pdf is not a regular html page, so the favicon is not defined as it could be. *The fallback is the favicon with the .ico extension in my public folder.*

But if thats the case then it should show my favicon that is already in the public folder?

The pdf is linked this way, I use the [Link Mui](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/link/) component:

```
<Link
href="/documents/Privacy-Policy"
target="_blank"
rel="noopener noreferrer">
Privacy Policy
</Link>
```

What can I do so my favicon or at least no favicon shows up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

In production it shows no favicon on Chrome and Firefox.
While on localhost it still shows the default React favicon on Chrome and Firefox.

Best case would be to have also my favicon when I open the pdf in Browser but no favicon is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your public folder, check the index.html file.

You will see `<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />`

Edit it to any image name of your choice.

In my case, I would use `<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo.svg" />` to denote my preferred image name

Comment: He explicitely said that his favicon is working. This is not the answer to the question

Comment: I know how to replace the default favicon with mine. This is not the problem. When I open a pdf then it defaults to the react favicon althogh I deleted it.

Comment: If there are multiple <link rel="icon">s, the browser uses their media attribute, type, and sizes attributes to select the most appropriate icon. If several icons are equally appropriate, the last one is used. If the most appropriate icon is later found to be inappropriate, for example because it uses an unsupported format, the browser proceeds to the next-most appropriate. 
Try this out... Use either .png files or .ico files

`<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">`

Comment: I have only one <link rel="icon"> and I only use .ico file. Nothing fancy in the setup its all default like when you create a react app with the template

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can just rename it from **logo.ico** to **favicon.ico** (which is the name of the default react favicon).